# Embed perl inside YAML file

Tags: perl, embed, yaml

I want to create YAML config. files inside which I can put in perl code to reduce the effort of writing the same blocks multiple times. Or for any other operation. I would like to have something like this inside my YAML file:

```
---
    `my $a = 1;`
    `if($a){`
    foo: bar
    `}else{`
    foo: baz
    `}
...
```

As is obvious, I want key 'foo' to be assigned the value 'bar' in this example.

Is this a good or a bad idea? If latter, what's the best way to write the file and the pre-processor for such a file?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. This turns a simple markup (just like XML - simple? - or JSON) into a frankenstein monster that requires custom handling and can introduce security vulnerabilities. Perhaps the YAML can encode different properties based on different *keys* in the YAML? For instance, maybe there is a 'debug' key and a 'production' key? The YAML consumer would then select the appropriate key (on, say, whatever is in $a). On the other hand, if this is only for a *build configuration*, then handle that separately (even, say the old CPP) during the build/deployment process.

Comment: I have to agree that this is a bad idea.  If you really want to have "executable perl in a config file," why even get YAML involved?  Go `eval` the contents of a file, and expect it to return a hash-ref.  Not exactly safe, but if you're in a closed environment, it could work.

Answer (score 3):

This is a not a good idea, but CAN be made better.

You have two approaches:

1. Treat your YAML / JSON file as a template for one of standard Perl templating systems.

   Embperl is a good candidate in my opinion, but that's because it's what I'm very familiar with. Any templating framework that supports control flow will fit.

   This way, you don't need to write your own language/syntax; AND you get a produced final YAML/XML/JSON in pure form so there's no need for a custom parser.
2. Create a Perl-based format.

   E.g. your config is a chunk of Perl code that is in essence an eval-able (or `do`-able) code chunk resulting in a config hash.

   The result hash structure ca be anything you want, but if you wish it to be, it can mirror the original JSON/YAML, and can be converted to one using standard conversion tools.